# Positioning relative to a \progressbar

Tags: tikz-pgf, beamer, positioning

I would like illustrate a deliberately overfull progressbar. I am using `\progressbar` and `tikz`, but the relative positioning (`east`) is always off by a bit in the X direction and I don't know why. Consider the following example:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage{progressbar}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
  \begin{overprint}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture]
      \node<1-2> (progressbar) [inner sep=0,outer sep=0] {\progressbar[heightr=1, width=0.3\textwidth, emptycolor=white, filledcolor=red]{1}};
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \tikz[remember picture] \draw<2>[overlay] node at (progressbar.east) [inner sep=0,outer sep=0] {\progressbar[heightr=1, width=0.1\textwidth, linecolor=white!0, emptycolor=white, filledcolor=red, subdivisions=1, roundnessr=0]{1}};
  \end{overprint}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

The first slide (cropped) looks like this:

[image: Progressbar]

The second slide (cropped) looks like this (note the second `\progressbar` at around 85%, not 100):

[image: Progressbar with incorrect relative position]

How can I position the second `\progressbar` relative to the first so that they don't overlap (disregarding the ugly white border)?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Like this?

[image: Result]

The problem is that, by default, it is the center of your second progress bar what is placed at `(progressbar.east)`. You want the left edge at that position, which is achieved by using `[anchor=west]` for that node. I.e.:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage{progressbar}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
  \begin{overprint}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture]
      \node<1-2> (progressbar) [inner sep=0,outer sep=0] {\progressbar[heightr=1, width=0.3\textwidth, emptycolor=white, filledcolor=red]{1}};
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \tikz[remember picture] \draw<2>[overlay] node[anchor=west] at (progressbar.east) [inner sep=0,outer sep=0] {\progressbar[heightr=1, width=0.1\textwidth, linecolor=white!0, emptycolor=white, filledcolor=red, subdivisions=1, roundnessr=0]{1}};
  \end{overprint}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Side note: I don't like very much that code, because it uses tikz code inside nodes (`\progressbar` command is indeed a complete `tikzpicture`), but I don't know how to avoid that in this case.

## Update

The code can be improved a bit. You can draw the second overlay in the same `tikzpicture` than the first one. This removes the need of `remember picture`/`overlay`, and needs one less compilation:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{progressbar}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
  \begin{overprint}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
      \node<1-2> (progressbar) [inner sep=0,outer sep=0] {\progressbar[heightr=1, width=0.3\textwidth, emptycolor=white, filledcolor=red]{1}};
      \node<2>[anchor=west] at (progressbar.east) [inner sep=0,outer sep=0] {\progressbar[heightr=1, width=0.1\textwidth, linecolor=white!0, emptycolor=white, filledcolor=red, subdivisions=1, roundnessr=0]{1}};
    \end{tikzpicture}
  \end{overprint}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I was not aware of the default assumption (center).

Comment: @AndreasUnterweger I noticed that the second `\tikz` is not required. I've updated the answer.